# HLS stream not working on Apple devices

Tags: ios, safari, vlc, http-live-streaming

I have a live RTSP stream that i have managed to transcode to HLS via VLC. Now it works perfect on Android and on desktop browsers (via flash).

But not on Apple (i can test it on iPad and desktop Safari on my virtual machine). I can see the player but when i press the 'play' button all i see is a black rectangle inside the player. On desktop Safari there is also a text 'Loading...' near the play/pause button and nothing else happens.

My HTML:

```
<video id="player" controls style="width:100%; height:100%">
  <source src="http://178.79.164.114/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

The command for vlc:

```
vlc -I dummy rtsp://<stream-url> --sout '#transcode{width=320,height=240,fps=25,vcodec=h264,vb=256,acodec=none,venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=30,bframes=0,ref=1,nocabac}}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,index=/path/to/server/directory/playlist.m3u8,index-url=http://178.79.164.114/seg-########.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/path/to/server/directory/seg-########.ts}'
```

And an example of the playlist file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:179
#EXTINF:9.60,
http://178.79.164.114/seg-00000179.ts
#EXTINF:9.60,
http://178.79.164.114/seg-00000180.ts
#EXTINF:9.60,
http://178.79.164.114/seg-00000181.ts
#EXTINF:9.61,
http://178.79.164.114/seg-00000182.ts
#EXTINF:9.59,
http://178.79.164.114/seg-00000183.ts
```

And here is the strange output of `ffprobe http://178.79.164.114/playlist.m3u8` (why there are these N/A and the variant_bitrate is 0?). Maybe it can help:

```
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://178.79.164.114/playlist.m3u8':
  Duration: N/A, start: 3995.330722, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 11:12 DAR 11:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I have also configured correct MIME types for .m3u8 and .ts files and spent a day searching and trying different options for the transcode command: width, height, bitrate, fps, different profiles and levels... - nothing works. But if i try some examples from apple (http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8) - all is fine, though it's not a live stream.

If anyone has any ideas or has a possibility to test my stream with the `mediastreamvalidator` - please help.

**UPDATE**

Now i'm experimenting with variant playlist but it changes nothing.

Comment: `variant_bitrate : 0` is displayed when you're not using a variant playlist. Can you try to put a silent audio track and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @aergistal sorry, had no possibility to test earlier. And it works, thank you!! But why it doesn't without an audio track? Is it a documented behavior? Also you can create an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hls video streaming on iOS/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287226/hls-video-streaming-on-ios-safari)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The player might expect muxed video and audio so add a silent audio track.

The [Apple HLS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html) says:

> The media segment files are normally produced by the stream segmenter, based on input from the encoder, and consist of a series of .ts files containing segments of an MPEG-2 Transport Stream carrying H.264 video **and** AAC, MP3, or AC-3 audio

Support for audio-only streams is mentioned in [Technical Note TN2224](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-AUDIOONLYSTREAM) and the 7th revision of the protocol introduced support for alternate renditions (unmuxed streams) but this is done with `EXT-X-MEDIA` tags in a master playlist controlling the playback (yours is a media playlist).