# Play self generated ts playlist in iOS

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts, hls.js

I have written a java program that accepts frames from camera using rtsp, creates MPEG2-TS file along with index.m3u8. This ts generation is done by simply adding PATs/PMTs etc. by simple bit level operations(i.e, without using any library like ffmpeg).
I am able to play the index file using ---- 

**hls.js** : 
Windows(Chrome, firefox is playing pretty good)
Android(firefox is playing fine, but updated chrome is unable to play, it says HLS.js not supported. Once I uninstall the updates of chrome, it can play it)

iOS(safari and chrome can play pretty good)

**clappr.js**- I think this is a pretty efficient library

Windows(Chrome, firefox is playing pretty good)
Android(Chrome, firefox is playing fine)

iOS(safari and chrome can play pretty good)

**VLC** plays good in Windows, android and iOS(MAC)

**Android Media Player** plays good when I integrated it in my android app.

**AVPlayer in iOS(MAC/iPhone/iPAD) : It simply cant play the TS !**

I am pretty confused and do not know what really the problem is. I think apple has some restrictions on ts (i.e, they need some more data in ts). Can someone help in this regard?

If this information is not enough to solve the problem, please suggest me, I'll provide.

Comment: How can we know what is wrong if you don’t post the files? All we can do is guess. Please don’t wast the time of people you are asking for help.

Comment: thanks for your response @szatmary, here is the google drive link containing generated ts files along with m3u8 : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11-QeDGHA7yMUYzSFVQWmZ3cHM

Comment: can someone please check and let me know if these files are ok or not?
I didn't parse the h.264 data coming from camera, I just form TS header, PES header and put the H.264 data into TS.

Comment: I am totally confused,, is this the problem of my ts ?

Comment: Hi, @szatmary, can you please have a look at the problem?

Comment: @vs93 You have continuity and PCR errors (deltas up to 1080 ms, max is 100 ms). There's also no audio. Adding silence [used to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328829/hls-stream-not-working-on-apple-devices/33433528#33433528) on some iOS devices.

Comment: @aergistal is having no audio an issue? I really donot want to have audio.
Also how can I resolve the continuity and PCR error?